# Find the probability density function $f_{X,Y}$ of $F_{X,Y}$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, partial-derivative, density-function

How do I find probability density function $f_{X,Y}$ of this multivariable function $F_{X,Y}$ where $\Phi$ is normal distribution function, $\alpha \in [0,1]$ and $\mu, \sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ and
$$ F_{X,Y} = \alpha \Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)\Phi(y) + (1-\alpha) \Phi\left(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)\Phi(x) $$

$f_{X,Y}$ has to be expressed through $\sigma_i, \mu_i$ and $\alpha$.
We don't know if these functions are independent in fact we actually later have to find the $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ where they are independent.
I'm guessing I have to use the formula
$$ f_{X,Y} = \frac{\partial^2 F_{X,Y}}{\partial x \partial y}, $$
but this gets quite ugly in my opinion. I have a feeling that the answer should be simpler.

Comment: Differentiating w.r.t $x$ and $y$ is the only way and I don't see anything ugly coming in.

Comment: If they are independent then $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)$.  There is an obvious set of values of the $\mu$s and $\sigma^2$s  which work for any $\alpha$, as well as two values of $\alpha$ which work for any sensible values of the $\mu$s and $\sigma^2$s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sigma_1}\cdot\alpha \phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)\phi(y) + \frac{1}{\sigma_2}\cdot(1-\alpha) \phi\left(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)\phi(x) $$
where $\phi$ is the density function of the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$